# How does one make a custom seed Rakefile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, seed

I'm looking to take some yml :

```
My Random Name of a Topic:
  Color:
    Brown
    Blue
    Green
  Style:
    Thin
    Fat
```

And I'd like to make a `Topic` object, and an `Item` object for all the words in Type and Style combined.

Each of those words will have a `type` attribute, that will say if its a `style` or `color`

Topics have a HABTM with Items, so I would also like to build this connection as well.

But not to ask someone to plow through a huge answer, I'm merely looking at the best way to parse this yaml :

```
task glass_full_of_yaml: :environment do
  File.open(Rails.root + 'lib/words/glass_full_of.yml', 'r') do |file|
    YAML::load(file).each do |record|
      debugger
      # Item.create!(type: record, name: record)
    end
  end
end
```

If all my topics are named differently, how can I select its nested attributes and create Item objects out of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
YAML::load(file).each do |topic, item_types|
  Topic.create! :name => topic, :items => item_types.map { |type, names|
    names.split(' ').map { |name|
      Item.new :type => type, :name => name
    }
  }.flatten
end
```